# Continuous, increasing function twice differentiable at a point must be once continuously differentiable in a neighbourhood.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

My lecturer made the following claim, which I have been trying hard to prove:

Suppose $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is strictly increasing, continuous and $f$ is *twice* differentiable at some point $x$ satisfying $f'(x)\neq 0$. Then $f$ is *continuously differentiable* in a neighbourhood of $x$.

---

Presumably this depends crucially on the strictly increasing hypothesis, but I can't manage to make use of this fact!

Comment: I don't believe it. Of course $f$ must be differentiable in a neighborhood in order for $f''(x)$ to exist, so a counterexample will have to be a differentiable function such that $f'$ has  infinitely many discontinuities, tending to $x$. Writing down such a thing might be a pain - why don't you see what he says when you ask him to prove it?

Comment: Actually it does not depend on strict monotonicity. Could you provide some context? Is this your first real analysis course?